# Swift: return number < 10

Tags: swift

That's the code:

```
import Foundation

func hasAnyMatches(list: [Int], condition: Int -> Bool) -> Bool {
    for item in list {
        if condition(item) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func lessThanTen(number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number < 10
}

var numbers = [20, 19, 7, 12]
hasAnyMatches(numbers, condition: lessThanTen)
```

There is a `return true` within the *if condition* and a `return false` at the end of `func hasAnyMatches()`. Why is the `return false` needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without explicitly "telling it" to return something, no function returns `false` "automatically". I am not writing in swift but I am sure if you take away the  `return false` it'll throw a warning.

The `lessThanTen` simply returns a bool if the number is smaller than 10.

`number < 10` is a statement checking if something is `true` or `false`. Hence the return type `bool` of `lessThanTen`

Comment: Exactly, depending on the value given it'll determine if the statement is correct or not. Keep in mind that 10 is for example not smaller than 10, you can combine < and > with = which leads to >= and <= (smaller or equals and greater or equals)

Comment: `return` only returns from one function. It doesn't escape from `lessThanTen` all the way out of `hasAnyMatches`.

Comment: To add more detail on the `<` front, the definition is `func <(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Bool`. This is an operator which takes two Ints and returns a Bool. `return number < 10` is the same as `let result = number < 10; return result`.

Comment: Similarly, `condition` is a function `Int -> Bool`. You give it an Int, it returns a Bool (it's a predicate). The `hasAnyMatches` function is correct.

Comment: `condition` is a function. It calls the function. In your example, you pass the `lessThanTen` function to the `condition` parameter.

Comment: It completely depends on the function. In your example, and true to its name, `lessThanTen` returns true when the number is less than 10.

Comment: OK we might need to add here that instead of if (statement==true) you can just type if (statement). The ==true is redundant. On the other hand, for (statement==false) you can just type (!statement).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like, for such condition.

```
let LESS_THAN_TEN = 1
let LESS_THAN_HUNDRED = 2

func hasAnyMatch (list: [Int], condition: Int)-> Bool{
 var x = false;
 switch  condition {
 case LESS_THAN_TEN :
    for a in list {
        if a < 10 {
            x = true
                break
            }
        }
 break

 case LESS_THAN_HUNDRED :
    for a in list {
        if a < 100 {
            x = true
            break
        }
    }

 break

 default:
    x = false
}
   return x
}

var isLessThanTen = hasAnyMatch([14, 45, 12, 65], condition: LESS_THAN_TEN)
print(isLessThanTen)
```